# Play Java Framework, how to store JSON objects coming from single JSON through Post request?

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson

I am trying to have a simple post controller reading and manipulating the content coming from a JSON served with a post request. But I only understood how to read one attribute from the first object, while the JSON contains a list of them.
Unfortunately the official documentation is not really the best for who is weak like me, so would it be possible to obtain a simple code with the core functionalities considering that I have to sort the list of objects coming from JSON?

#### My Json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "James",
    "starttime": "2011-04-19T06:16:56-07:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jack",
    "starttime": "2014-11-07T21:12:11-07:00"
  }
]
```

#### My class:

```
package controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class CustomersController extends Controller {
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result index() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        String name = json.findPath("name").textValue();
        if(name == null) {
            return badRequest("Missing parameter [name]");
        } else {
            return ok("Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

And what I obtain on my Restful client as response:

```
Hello James!
```

So, how to read all the objects? How to use Object mapper or the Jackson functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

Json object mapping (which uses Jackson under the hood) is part of Playframework: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions#Mapping-Java-objects-to-JSON

```
public class Foo {
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public Date date;
}

public class CustomersController extends Controller {
   @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
   public Result index() {
      JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
      Foo foo1 = Json.fromJson(json, Foo.class);
      return ok("Hello " + foo1.name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the request payload is an array :

```
public class CustomersController extends Controller {
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result index() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        if (!node.isArray()) {
            return badRequest("You need to send a JSON array");
        }

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        node.fields().forEachRemaining(item -> {
            names.add("Name : " + item.getValue().get("name").asText());
        });

        // Do what you want with your list...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the array into an object and give it a key .. then map it to a class if needed

```
{"array_key" :[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "James",
    "starttime": "2011-04-19T06:16:56-07:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jack",
    "starttime": "2014-11-07T21:12:11-07:00"
  }
]}

    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    ArrayNode node1= (ArrayNode)json.withArray("array_key");
            Iterator<JsonNode> jn1=node1.elements();
            List<class_name_of_list> list1=new ArrayList<class_name_of_list>();
            while(jn1.hasNext())
            {
                ObjectNode on1=(ObjectNode) jn1.next();                                         
                class_name_of_list obj1 = Json.fromJson(on1, class_name_of_list.class);

                 list1.add(obj1);
            }
            if(list1.size()>0)
                Ebean.save(list1);
```